# Delete cookie data

Tags: apex, visualforce, cookies

I've created a cookie as shown and append any newly added data to the cookie:

```
if (cart == null) {
               //Create an instance of the cookieJar class, passing it the values entered in the fields
                cookieJar c = new cookieJar(p.productid, selSize, selColour, String.valueOf(p.qtyToBuy));          
            } else {   //Append cookie
               String pid = cart.getValue();
               String psize = cart2.getValue();
               String pqty = cart3.getValue();
               String pcol = cart4.getValue();

               cookieJar c = new cookieJar(p.productid + ',' + pid, selSize + ',' + psize, selColour + ',' + pcol ,String.valueOf(p.qtyToBuy) + ',' + pqty);

            }
```

I would like to delete the cookie data based on the productid. Is there way to do so?
I understand from documentation that  ***After you create a cookie, the properties of the cookie can't be changed.***
Does that mean that I can't delete the cookie?

On the other hand, I've tried using Javascript on my VF page to delete the particular cookie with product id, but it doesn't seems to work.

```
        <apex:column headerValue="Product" value="{!item.Name}"/>
       <apex:column headerValue="Colour" value="{!item.Color}"/> 
       <apex:column headerValue="Size" value="{!item.Size}"/> 
       <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">
            <apex:outputText value="{!item.qtyToBuy}" />
        </apex:column>

          <apex:column headerValue="Remove">
          <apex:commandLink action="{!removecon}" reRender="s" >
          <apex:param assignTo="{!conid}" value="{!item.productid}" name="assignvalue" />Remove </apex:commandLink> 
        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" oncomplete="deletecook();" reRender="s" />
        </apex:column>

        </apex:pageblocktable>        
    </apex:pageblock>

  <script>
function deletecook() {
document.cookie = "productid='{!conid}'; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
 alert(document.cookie);
 }
```

Cookie Jar Class

```
public class cookieJar {


        // The controller extension does the work
        public cookieJar(String productid, String productsize, String productcolour, String qtyToBuy) {

            Cookie pId = new Cookie('productid', productid,null,-1,false);
            Cookie pSize = new Cookie('productSize', productsize,null,-1,false);
            Cookie qty = new Cookie('qtyToBuy', qtyToBuy,null,-1,false);
            Cookie pCol = new Cookie('productColour', productcolour,null,-1,false);

            //Set the page cookies using the setCookies() method
            ApexPages.currentPage().setCookies(new Cookie[]{pId, pSize, pCol, qty});

        }


    }//end cookieJar inner class
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks guys!

Comment: I know this might not be the answer you might be looking for, but can you have an expiry date on the cookie? It`s just a suggestion

Comment: Hi @MihaiNeagoe, thanks for your reply. Expiry date, yes I've set the date to 0, but it won't work as I'm using a custom apex cookie class to store the value here: http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/storing-form-field-values-with-the-apex-cookie-class

Answer (score 6):

You just have to set the maxAge value to zero, which is the equivalent of the standard way of setting the expiry date on the past.

From the documentation: [Cookie Class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_sites_cookie.htm)

> MaxAge: A number representing how long a cookie is valid for in seconds. If
>   set to less than zero, a session cookie is issued. If set to zero, the
>   cookie is deleted.

E.g. based on cookie set in `cookieJar`

```
Cookie pId = new Cookie('productid', '',null,0,false); // Note the 0 to delete the cookie
ApexPages.currentPage().setCookies(new Cookie[]{pId});
```

Comment: Hi @pepeFloyd, thanks for your reply. Yes I've read the documentation, but am not sure on how do I remove the data based on the id found within the appended cookie.

Comment: @taradyn CookieJar [appears to be a custom Apex Class](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/storing-form-field-values-with-the-apex-cookie-class). The Cookie id will be defined there.

Comment: HI @DanielBallinger , thanks  for your reply. I'm kinda confused. What do you mean by the cookie id will be defined there? Yes, I'm using the exact custom apex class. My cookiejar constructor contained the product id. As you can see my cookie data is appended. I tried to remove the the cookie based on the specific product id but failed.

Comment: @taradyn The first parameter passed to the `Cookie` constructor in `CookieJar` with be the Cookie Id you need. If that doesn't make sense, can you add your `CookieJar` implementation to the question.

Comment: Hi, @DanielBallinger I've added the cookie Jar class. The first parameter in the constructor is my product id.

Comment: Hi @DanielBallinger, I've tried setting the productid maxage to 0.  But I'll get "Attempt to de-reference a null object." I can understand why as the cookie is deleted when it navigates to a new page. I can't set the cookie to 0 as I need to retained the cookie info. The deletion of cookie will occurs when I tried to remove it from a page block table. Nevertheless, thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting maxAge -1, set it to 0.
It will delete the cookie.

You can use the [Apex Cookie class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites_cookie.htm).